# I can't seem to retrieve SharePoint 2013 list items via Powershell

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I have a short script which is going to be part of a larger one but I can't get it to work.  It works on every other list I've tried running it against but not this one in particular.  The `$myList.ItemCount` returns the correct number of list items as 4987 but the $items.Count returns 0 and the `foreach` loop returns no results.  Anyone ever deal with this issue?  I'm sure it has something to do with the list itself as I made a template of it, copied it to another site, ran the exact same script with the updated url and it worked.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue 

$myWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://mysiteurl.org"
$myList = $myWeb.Lists["My List"]
$myView = $myList.Views["All Items"]
$items = $myList.GetItems($myView)

Write-Output $myList.ItemCount
write-output $items.Count

foreach($item in $items)
{
Write-Output $item
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try without using any view

```
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://mysiteurl.org"
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["My List"]
$SPListItems = $SPList.Items #or $SPList.GetItems()
$SPListItems.Count
$SPWeb.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the script and it is working fine, i think you have to check couple of things:

- Make sure it is list not a library, if it is not a list then view will be different. i.e. for document library it will be `All Documents`
  Run the below script to get the all views from the list.

> $myWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://mysiteurl.org"
>
> ```
> $myList = $myWeb.Lists["My List"]
>
> $myView = $myList.Views
>
> $myView.views.Title
> ```

Now review the output and you will see if All items or any other All type of view available.